# 'list' command isn't working on shell for Hbase 0.90.x

Tags: hbase

I try  HBase 0.90.x and HBase 0.94.x . If I start HBase 0.94.6 ,no problem. If I start HBase 0.90.5 or 0.90.6, not run `list` command at shell. No response, no error in log. When this command is running constantly waiting.

but run following command:

> hbase(main):001:0> create 'test','cf'

Only list command isn't run for HBase 0.90.x and constantly waiting.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is resolved.

**hbase-site.xml** is checked. Add property correctly as follow:

```
    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>file:///home/gyhot/hbase-datadir-90-5</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
        <value>/home/gyhot/zookeeper-datadir/</value>
    </property>
    <property>
                <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
                <value>true</value>
    </property>
```